# How to save / Load NSUserDefaults for backup purposes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Is this code correct to load and save NSUserDefaults.

```
// Load
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
         dictionaryRepresentation];

// Save
    NSDictionary *dict =  ....
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults registerDefaults:dict];
    [defaults synchronize]; << Not sure if this is needed
```

I'm using JSON to hold the dictionary contents and I'm having problems. 
I'd just like to know if this code is correct, before I look elsewhere for my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *Load* code will get you a dictionary of all the current default values.

[*Note* This will probably be much larger than you expect as Mac OS installs a raft of defaults, you might want to make it smaller. For example, you can limit the dictionary to just those defaults in your domain *which differ from* their registered default using:

```
NSDictionary *userDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] persistentDomainForName:@"<your bundle identifier>"];
```

*end note*]

Your *Save* code probably doesn't do what you expect, it installs the values you are restoring as the *defaults* for those keys - so if you support "Restore to Default Settings", or something similar, then these are the values that would result. What you probably want to do it set the *current* value of the keys, this can be done with a simple loop:

```
NSDictionary *dict =  ....
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
foreach(id key in dict)
   [defaults setObject:[dict objectForKey:key] forKey:key];
```

The above code is only an outline, you may need to take care what preferences you save/restore and in what order - but all that depends on your application.

Comment: The only concern I have with the save is that it use setobject whereas I use seinteger as well in places, would set object cover both. Having said that why have setinteger if setobject would do this.

Comment: The data structures behind `NSUserDefaults` store objects, the `NSDictionary` created by reading in the file also stores objects, hence the use of `setObject:`. In the case of integer values the actual object stored is an `NSNumber`. `setInteger`, and the other primitive type setters and getters are convenience methods which (un)wrap the primitive values from/as objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get

NSDictionary *dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myDictionary"];

// Set

NSDictionary *dict = ...

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dict forKey:@"myDictionary"];
```

Comment: I have lots of settings Im trying to do all at once.